# What is the best way to address a circular duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

While looking up a fairly basic [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) question I came across the following:

1. Open, -1 score,  asked 12 months ago: [How do I check to see if a text file is empty or does not exist in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53678811)
2. Closed as duplicate of 1, 37 score,  asked 9 years, 9 months ago: [Checking for an empty file in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390912)
3. Closed as duplicate of 1, 41 score, asked 10 years, 1 month ago: [ifstream: how to tell if specified file doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647557)

As you can see, questions (2) and (3) are significantly older than (1) which was selected as the "canonical" answer despite the low score. Question (2) also has a much better answer given as well. My inclination would be to reopen (2) and vote to close (1) as a duplicate, but given the circular references, what would be the ideal way to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions 2 and 3 may be *related*, but they are distinct: checking whether a file exists is different from checking whether it is empty. As such, neither question 2 nor question 3 should be closed as a duplicate (unless you find an *actual* duplicate, other than the questions referenced here), so I’d reopen.

Question 1 is a recent, relatively low-quality question, which is a duplicate of both questions 2 and 3. As such, I would recommend closing it as a duplicate of question 2, and then subsequently adding question 3 to the list of duplicates.

<strike>If you need any help doing this, please feel free to let me know. I'd do it myself, but I’m currently on mobile, where closing is unnecessarily difficult.</strike>
[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: Well, the tricky bit is that the back-end recognizes the circular reference if you try to close (1) as a duplicate of (2). So it seems that (2) needs to be reopened before (1).

Comment: Yes, that’s correct. You need to reopen first, before closing.

Comment: Well, I only have 13k reputation so, not enough power to do that. :(

Comment: @rjzii If you have a gold badge in the tag you can open and close duplicates with one vote.

Comment: @JL2210 Well I don't have a gold badge either. :(

Comment: Ah, I assumed you had a gold badge. Okay, keep working on earning that, and I’ll handle the closing/reopening. :-)